# Airflow passing Snowflake session_parameters

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

As you can see in the code example, I'm trying to pass session_parameters to my Snowflake connection through Airflow DAG Task, but the parameter is not being picked up, any solution to that?

```python
task = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='Task',
    sql="CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (test VARCHAR)",
    session_parameters={
        "QUERY_TAG": "my_tag"
    },
    snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_connection",
    warehouse="MY_WH",
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using an outdated version of the snowflake operator.
Support for `session_parameters`  was added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12071)

---

For `Airflow>=2.3.0` you will need to have:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-common-sql
pip install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake
```

Then you can use your code as:

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

task = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id='Task',
    conn_id="snowflake_connection",
    sql="CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (test VARCHAR)",
    hook_params={
        "session_parameters": {"QUERY_TAG": "my_tag"},
        "warehouse": "MY_WH"
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

The `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` is generic operator. Under the hood it uses `SnowflakeHook` to interact with Snowflake.

---

For `2.0.0<=Airflow<2.3.0` you will need to have:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake
```

Then you can use your code as:

```
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
task = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='Task',
    sql="CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (test VARCHAR)",
    session_parameters={
        "QUERY_TAG": "my_tag"
    },
    snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_connection",
    warehouse="MY_WH",
    dag=dag,
)
```

Noting `SnowflakeOperator` is [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/35845f9fb62a261c956f32d64516b637b18369fa/airflow/providers/snowflake/operators/snowflake.py#L105), this approach will work also with newer versions of Airflow till the operator is removed from Snowflake provider.

---

For `Airflow<2.0.0` you will need to have:

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-snowflake>='2020.11.23'
```